# How to fix 401 status code discord OAuth2 request while using the right access token (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, discord

I have a problem using the discord OAuth2 requests here is my code:

```js
function fetchDiscord(api, access_token) {
    return fetchNode(`https://discord.com/api/${api}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        },
    }).then(response => response.json());
}

passport.use(
    new DiscordStrategy(
        {
            clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: process.env.CLIENT_REDIRECT,
            scope: ["identify", "email", "guilds", "messages.read"],
            passReqToCallback: true,
        },
        async (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            console.log("====================================");
            console.log(profile);
            console.log("====================================");
            fetchDiscord(`guilds/${profile.guilds[0].id}/channels`, accessToken).then((response) => {
                var username = `${profile.username}#${profile.discriminator}`;
                var accessTokens = [
                    { token: accessToken, id: profile.id },
                    ...(req.session?.passport?.user?.accessTokens || []),
                ];
                var refreshTokens = [
                    { token: refreshToken, id: profile.id },
                    ...(req.session?.passport?.user?.refreshTokens || []),
                ];
                const user = { ...profile };
                done(null, {
                    user_id: user.id,
                    guilds: user.guilds,
                    email: user.email,
                    username,
                    accessTokens,
                    refreshTokens,
                });
            })
        }
    )
);
```

the client Id and everything are set, and after following the documentation this is what I got, and no it is not for a bot

just to test the access token I called the request right after I got the it, but sadly all I got was 401 status

`{message: '401: Unauthorized', code: 0}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Get Channels is only made for bots.

thus I cannot use this method with normal accounts "Bearer {access_token}", I need a bot "Bot {access_token}" to access this it.